# I need to read one Excel file, parse and write the results to another Excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I can't figure out why I am getting an error message when trying to compile my code.  I need to read 21 lines from the input file to create one new record in an existing excel file.  Then I need repeat the process for about 3000 lines of input.

At my While statement it highlights (filenum) and I get the error message:
Compile Error; Expected End Sub

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications
---------------------------
Compile error:

Expected End Sub
---------------------------
OK   Help   
---------------------------
```

Here is some of the code:

```
Sub btnProcessData_Click()

Dim FileNum As Integer
FileNum = FreeFile()

Open "filename" For Input As #FileNum

Dim DataLine As String
Dim strCallNum As String
a bunch of Dim statements appear here

While Not EOF(FileNum)
 Sub CallInvoiceNums()
    Line Input #FileNum, strDataLine
     strCallNum = strDataLine
     MsgBox strCallNum
     Line Input #FileNum, strDataLine
     strInvoiceNum = strDataLine
     MsgBox strInvoiceNum
    Line Input #FileNum, strDataLine
     strText_String = strDataLine
     MsgBox strText_String

      Sub Break_String()
       WrdArray() = Split(text_string)
       For i = LBound(WrdArray) To UBound(WrdArray)
         strg = strg & vbNewLine & "Part No. " & i & " - " & WrdArray(i)
       Next i
       strArrayElements = UBound(WrdArray, 2)
       MsgBox strg
      End Sub
 End Sub
Wend

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have formatted your code so it is readable. To do this I selected the code and then clicked the button with curly braces. I suspect the unreadable code was the cause of the down votes.

You are declaring a sub within another.  You have:

```
Sub btnProcessData_Click()
 . . .
While Not EOF(FileNum)
Sub CallInvoiceNums()
```

You must end `btnProcessData` with `End Sub` before you can start `Sub CallInvoiceNums`.

Sub and Function declarations cannot be nested.  Try separating your subs then come back if you need further help.

**Update**

Near the end of your code you have:

```
  Sub Break_String()
   WrdArray() = Split(text_string)
   For i = LBound(WrdArray) To UBound(WrdArray)
     strg = strg & vbNewLine & "Part No. " & i & " - " & WrdArray(i)
   Next i
   strArrayElements = UBound(WrdArray, 2)
   MsgBox strg
  End Sub
```

This looks as though you thought about splitting this code out as a subroutine but did not.  If you deleted `Sub Break_String()` and `End Sub`, it looks as though the remaining code would work.  The same is true for `Sub CallInvoiceNums()` and its matching `End Sub`.  Are you perhaps familiar with a language with a different method of declaring subroutines and functions?

I do not understand your prefixes. I have programmed in languages were it was conventional to prefix variable names with a code that indicated their type.  "wrd" might be used for 16 or 32-bit integers but in `WrdArray`, you are using it for an array of strings.  You are storing a 32-bit integer in `strArrayElements`.  Please explain.

Comment: ! have tried putting in End Sub at different locations and, I each time I get the Compile Error:  Only Comments may appear after End Sub, End Functions and End Property.

Comment: @ThelmaG  We have guests at the moment so I am not sure when I will have the time to look at your code in detail.  Our friends leave on Wednesday so I will answer properly then if I cannot do so before.

Comment: @ThelmaG.  I have had a little time to look at your code.  What is the purpose of the line `Sub CallInvoiceNums()`?  If you omitted this line, the code would look sensible.  You appear to have a single sub `btnProcessData_Click()` and not a nested sub as I thought at first glance.

Comment: @ThelmaG  I have had a longer look at your code and have updated my answer with my thoughts.